# Add survey reply in document library on each uploaded document

Tags: design

I would like to link the survey reply item to the document library so that the user can provide survey response to the document which uploaded in this library. Is it possible to do so?
Thanks a lot
Kim

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a link directly to survey question instead of requiring clicking to respond, please use NewForm.aspx and see if it meet your requirement:

http://sp/sites/sitename/lists/survey1/newform.aspx